# Annoying ribbon blocks my screen on Cubot phone

Tags: notifications, cubot

I have a Cubot phone Android OS. It's a new phone and I have a very annoying problem. Every time I perform a function, a ribbon appears at the bottom of the screen telling me what function I am performing, for example, the Google Photos app logo and the words 'sharing to WhatsApp’ or ‘Uninstalling. . .’ etc.

I cannot get rid of this ribbon, and it hogs my screen for about 30 seconds. As it overlays whatever is behind it (and cannot be moved or deleted), I cannot see the keyboard or whatever else it’s overlaying, and I have to wait until the ribbon disappears on its own before I can use my phone again.

I have searched for months for information on this but cannot find any way to stop it from popping up. I’ve never had this problem on any other phone, and I’ve used Cubots for years.

Comment: Have you enabled Developer Options on that phone? Which Android version is installed?

Comment: This might be an accessibility feature, though I can't recall any that shows the user's action. However, the "*30 seconds*" reminds me of the "Time to take action" accessibility setting that affects toast-type messages. You might want to check/search it in the Android Settings.

Comment: Hi Andrew. I have just changed a setting under Accessibility - Timing Controls - Time to Take Action where it was set at 1min. I have changed it to default and it seems to have solved the issue, I hope. Thank you Andrew and Robert for responding.